# How to combine PHP, jquery, and Ajax for a dynamic site with some common behaviors?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How would I accomplish some common functions in a site. I am looking for best practices and general advise.

1. Is it worth it/recommended to pull a list of categories from a mysql table via php to populate a menu that will be "animated" with jquery or is it easier to use a static text if it is not going to change very often?
2. How would I accomplish the following: clicking on a category from a menu refreshes the main content to reflect the appropriate item results. I.e. how the products you are looking at on amazon.com change as you select categories and subcategories.  If all of my products or items are stored in mysql, should every click of a category results in a new query to mysql which is then displayed via ajax/jquery without refreshing the whole page.
3. Where do php includes fit it? If i can dynamically query and refresh page content should i bother creating php files with those queries and then pull them in instead? Does that ensure that people w/o JS can still view pages?
4. I started by learning php and am now learning jquery. What is best practice today for combining the two, should jquery take over as much function as possible or only those parts that I really need to be dynamic?

Answer (score -1):

combined these  two can make a very powerful tool. if you are willing to do so , i might suggest using a framework close to core php and proving a better coding structure to start with. You can use [Codeignitor](http://codeigniter.com/) . and it is a best practice to implement the user side functionalities with javascript as it will make ur app much faster and the only things that would be needed on the server side will be the higher logics like session, security, db functions etc.